# How can I execute this SQL query in Drupal?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'd like to execute the following SQL query in Drupal...but haven't had any luck.

```
SELECT SUM(field_count) FROM headon_entry WHERE uid = 1 AND tid = 263;
```

I've used the following, but with no luck:

```
$query = db_select('headon_entry', 'he')
  ->condition('uid', $uid)
  ->condition('tid', $product_id);
$query->addExpression('SUM(field_count)', 'field_count');
$entry_quantity = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query comes out as

```
SELECT SUM(field_count) AS field_count
FROM 
{headon_entry} he
WHERE  (uid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (tid = :db_condition_placeholder_1)
```

So what you've got is correct as far as building the query goes.

What you *haven't* done is extract the result from the query execution. Try this:

```
$entry_quantity = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```